# How to map bean property for one to many in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables `vehicleregister` and `groupdetails` for that I have beans as `VehicleRegisterBean` and `GroupDetails` common field is `groupid`. Here 1 group can contains many vehicles for that I am performing OnetoMany relation for that I have defined bean as,

VehicleRegiserBean ,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle_register")
public class VehicleRegisterBean {
 // somefields

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="groupid", nullable=false)
private GroupDetails groupDetails;

//getter setters
}
```

and

GroupDetails,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_details")
public class GroupDetails {

//some fields

@OneToMany(mappedBy="GroupDetails")
private Set<VehicleRegisterBean> vehicleRegisterBean;

//getters setters
}
```

but I am getting exception as,

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.abc.its.beans.VehicleRegisterBean.GroupDetails in com.abc.its.beans.GroupDetails.vehicleRegisterBean
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:685)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:645)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:65)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
```

can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for `mappedBy` attribute represents the field in your `VehicleRegisterBean` class which is `groupDetails` but you are using `GroupDetails` in `mappedBy`.

So hibernate is trying to look for property `GroupDetails` in `VehicleRegisterBean` and saying that it is not able to find that property. Thats is what the error says:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: 
com.abc.its.beans.VehicleRegisterBean.GroupDetails
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="GroupDetails")
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="groupDetails")
```

it is the name that you declare here,

```
private GroupDetails groupDetails;
```